# Calculate $61^{61} \pmod9$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have a solution in front of me, but several parts do not quite make sense to me.

Since $61 \equiv −2 \pmod9$, we have
$$61^{61} \equiv (−2)^{61}\equiv −2 \cdot 8^{60}\pmod{9}$$

**First question**: how do we get from $(-2)^{61}$ is congruent to $(-2)\cdot 8^{60}$?

$$-2\cdot 8^{60}\equiv −2 · (−1)^{61} \pmod{9}$$

**Second question:** how do we get from $-2 \cdot 8^{60}$ is congruent to $-2 
\cdot (-1)^{61}$?

$$\equiv −2 \equiv 7 \pmod 9.$$

Comment: $61^{61}\equiv(-2)^{61}\equiv(-2)(8)^{20}\equiv(-2)(-1)^{20}\equiv-2\equiv7\pmod9$

Comment: Careful; $-2^n\neq(-2)^n$

Comment: Alternatively, $61^{61}\equiv(-2)^{61}\equiv(-2)^{60}(-2)\equiv((-2)^6)^{10}\equiv-2\equiv7\bmod9$ by [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)

Comment: In my last comment, I meant $((-2)^6)^{10}\color{blue}{(-2)}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner please post your comments as an answer

Comment: Okay, @OmarS, I did

Answer (score 1):

$(-2)^{61}=-2\times(-2)^{3\times20}=-2\times(-8)^{20}=-2\times8^{20}≡-2\times(-1)^{20}=-2$.

Note $8≡-1$ (mod $9)$ and if $a ≡ b$ (mod $n$) and $c ≡ d$ (mod $n$) then $ac ≡ bd$ (mod $n$)

Comment: Did you mean to type $20$ where you typed $30$?

Comment: my mistake, i will edit.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$61^{61}\equiv(-2)^{61}\equiv(-2)(8)^{20}\equiv(-2)(-1)^{20}\equiv-2\equiv7\pmod9.$

Alternatively, by [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), $a^6\equiv1\pmod9$ if $\gcd(a,9)=1$,

so $61^{61}\equiv(-2)^{61}\equiv(-2)^{60}(-2)\equiv((-2)^6)^{10}(-2)\equiv7\pmod9.$